# Jest Testing React Native cannot use import statement outside of a module

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs

I have been trying to find out how to fix the following error when trying to run my Jest test using React Native:

> FAIL  **tests**/App-test.js   ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> /home/marijkebuurman/Desktop/sport-data-valley-questionnaire-app/node_modules/react-native/index.js:13
> import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>
>   at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
>   at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/native/lib/commonjs/useBackButton.tsx:3:1)
> ```

`package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.8",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.1.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.10",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-keychain": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation)"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried to fix the problem in my `package.json` file by using`transformIgnorePatterns` to try and ignore `react-navigation`, but this hasn't worked.

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
    "module:react-native-dotenv",
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "cwd": "babelrc",
        "root": [
          "./src"
        ],
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".ios.js",
          ".android.js"
        ],
        "alias": {
          "api": "./src/api",
          "assets": "./src/assets",
          "services": "./src/services",
          "styles": "./src/styles",
          "components": "./src/components",
          "app": "./src"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I've also installed and added `@babel/preset-flow` to the presets in my `.babelrc` file because I read somewhere this could help, but with no success.

My test

```
// import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', async () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

The test itself is pretty much the default provided React Native Jest test. I have commented the import statement for React Native as this was giving a similar error when running the test. When that line is uncommented the test still gives the error about `AccessibilityInfo` import statement, but there is no mention about `@react-navigation` but rather about `ScriptTransformer.js`.

My guess is that all this has something to do with my babel configuration, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried out a lot of changes to my `.babelrc` file, but I eventually fixed the error by converting my `.babelrc` file to a `babel.config.js` file that currently looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
      '@babel/preset-flow',
    ],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ['./src'],
          extensions: ['.js', '.ios.js', '.android.js'],
          alias: {
            api: './src/api',
            assets: './src/assets',
            services: './src/services',
            styles: './src/styles',
            components: './src/components',
            app: './src',
          },
        },
      ],
      ['transform-class-properties'],
    ],
  };
};
```

---

Aside from this I've added a lot of mocks inside my `__mocks__` directory for different packages like for example `react-native-firebase`. I pretty sure that the mock files I added didn't have a part in fixing the error in my question, but there were other similar errors that were fixed by adding mock files.

*By similar errors I mean errors that have an error message like*:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: I'm already using babel.config.js because the .rc file doesn't work with React Native (re: read at compile time). So I'm still looking for a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, fixing this error requires adding the library, which the error complains about to the `transformIgnorePatterns`, which is in the file `jest.config.js`.

```js
// jest.config.js 
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native', 
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    // 1. specific setup for react-native 
    '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect',

    // 2. global setup & mocking for some services: 
    './jest.setup.js',

    // 3. mocking for more services: 
    './__mocks__/react-native-firebase.js',
    "./__mocks__/@react-native-community/google-signin.ts", 
  ],
  // 4. You need to add the library to the RegEx below <- Problem Fix
  //    For example, if the error was related to "react-native-elements", you need to add it to the list (as shown below.) 
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|react-native-elements|@react-native(-community)?)/)"], 
}
```

`"react-native": "0.66.4"`

```
"@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.4"
"@testing-library/react-native": "^9.0.0"
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0"
"babel-jest": "^27.4.6"
"jest": "^27.4.7"
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2"
```