# React-Native Uncaught syntax error: Cannot import statement outside a module

Tags: react-native

Here is an image of the top lines of a simple(ish) app.js  (not using the bluetooth stuff yet - all commented out)

[image]

So no biggie as app seems to work regardless, but I'm interested in why I get it and what can be done to remove it.

Some previous questions seem related to the use of something called Jest (no idea what that is - I suppose I should look it up?)
[Jest Testing React Native cannot use import statement outside of a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158612/jest-testing-react-native-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-of-a-module)

Putting it here for benefit of others who may come across it.

Comment: When you hover on error, the editor needs to give you what is going wrong. You need to find the name of error first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: Funny: In resolving another issue and following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067004/invariant-violation-calling-synchronous-methods-on-native-modules-is-not-suppor/69139744#comment122675079_69139744 the error squiggles have disappeared?